# A list of three lists of tuples -> list of dictionaries?

Tags: python

I asked a similar question before, but I'm discovering new things about needing specific object types for FastAPI. I feel that I'm really close to the answer, but it still eludes me!

```
from workalendar.core import Calendar
from workalendar.registry import registry

CalendarClass = registry.get('US')
calendar = CalendarClass()

# Get the range of years
start_year = 2018
end_year = 2020
all_years = range(start_year, end_year + 1, 1)

# Get the holidays for each of the years
holiday_list = list()

for yearr in all_years:
    holiday_list.append(calendar.holidays(yearr))

holiday_list
```

Truncated output:

```
[[(datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), 'New year'),
(datetime.date(2019, 4, 19), 'Good Friday'),
...
(datetime.date(2019, 12, 26), 'Boxing Day')],
[(datetime.date(2020, 1, 1), 'New year'),
(datetime.date(2020, 4, 10), 'Good Friday'),
...
(datetime.date(2020, 12, 26), 'Boxing Day')],
[(datetime.date(2021, 1, 1), 'New year'),
(datetime.date(2021, 4, 2), 'Good Friday'),
...
(datetime.date(2021, 12, 25), 'Christmas Day'),
(datetime.date(2021, 12, 26), 'Boxing Day')]]
```

What I would like:

```
[{datetime.date(2019, 1, 1): 'New Year'},
{datetime.date(2019, 4, 19): 'Good Friday'},
...
{datetime.date(2020, 12, 26): 'Boxing Day'},
{datetime.date(2021, 1, 1): 'New year'},
...
{datetime.date(2021, 12, 25): 'Christmas Day'},
{datetime.date(2021, 12, 26): 'Boxing Day'}]
```

What I've tried (with some variations):

```
final_list = []
for inner_list in holiday_list:
    {inner_tuple[0]: inner_tuple[1] for sublist in final_list for inner_tuple in sublist}
```

Comment: What is your question? Is there a particular problem with what you've tried (with some variations)?

Comment: You want dictionary, but your expected output is set?

Comment: @MechanicPig `final_list` starts as an empty list, and finishes in empty list.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you are trying to convert a list of tuples into a dict. That can be done directly with the `dict` function

```py
lot = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
d = dict(lot)
```

output

```
{'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about setting your holiday list to the first year of the data generated and append the rest of the years. Wonder if it answers your question.

```
from workalendar.core import Calendar
from workalendar.registry import registry

CalendarClass = registry.get('US')
calendar = CalendarClass()

# Get the range of years
start_year = 2018
end_year = 2020
all_years = range(start_year, end_year + 1, 1)

# Get the holidays for each of the years
holiday_list = list()
for yearr in all_years:
    if holiday_list:
        holiday_list = calendar.holidays(yearr)
    else:
        holiday_list.append(calendar.holidays(yearr))

print(holiday_list)
```